# Kendo UI Chart Tooltip issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

We are using Kendo UI DataViz chart. It displays tooltip on mouse hover on the bar of chart. When we test it on the mobile, tooltip shows on finger touch, which is OK. But after a couple of touches, the application hangs.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same issue. Due to Kendo DataViz's jQuery dependency, I suspected the issue was queuing animations, so by subscribing to the the exposed DataViz seriesClick & seriesHover events (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#events-seriesClick) on chart init, I fixed mine by essentially fast-forwarding the [otherwise queued] animations:

```
    seriesClick: stopAnim,

    seriesHover: stopAnim

      ...

    function stopAnim(){
       $('.k-tooltip').stop(true, true);
    }
```